# Fastest way to extract two arrays from an object array in javascript

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose

Lets say I have a schema like this:

```
users: {
   friends: [{name: String, id: String}]
}
```

what is the fastest way to extract this object array into two separate arrays:

```
var names = [String]
var ids = [String]
```

Is there a way to do this without a for loop? This operation needs to be done for a set of users and im trying to avoid nested for loops. Maybe there is a better way to store the friends names and ids?

Comment: Most any solution is going to do iteration in one form or another at least under the hood.  If you need to transform the data for its only use then there probably is a better way to store or work with the data, but that's impossible to say without knowing how its used.  "Explode" isn't the right term for what you're looking to do, you should stick to something with less connotation like extract or transform.

Comment: Thank you I edited the question and removed the word explode

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's always a loop, somewhere (and I'm not sure what you mean by nested loops?). :)

If you're looking for fastest (which is what you had said), using a `map` or a `forEach` isn't generally speaking going to result in faster operation as each iteration is calling a function, which adds overhead.

As you'll see in this [jsPerf](http://jsperf.com/map-vs-not), it's generally better to use a for-loop construct. First, if the array is long, you'll benefit from only going through the array just once (rather than once for each property). For futher optimization, predeclaring the array size also can improve performance.

```
var names = new Array(totalFriends),
    ids = new Array(totalFriends), friend;

for (var j = 0; j < totalFriends; j++) {
  friend = friends[j];
  names[j] = friend.name;
  ids[j] = friend.id;
}
```

A map call is convenient, but likely not the fastest.

Comment: thank you for that. based on your recommendation I ended up using a for loop instead because it is definitely a lot faster.

Answer (score 3):

Use `Array.map()`:

```
var names = users.friends.map(function(o) { return o.name; }),
    ids   = users.friends.map(function(o) { return o.id;   });
```